# SQL insert datediff

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I am trying to run a SQL `INSERT` that will calculate a `DATEDIFF` on two dates.

Does anybody know if you can use `DATEDIFF` on SQL `INSERT` command?

I want column duration to be calculate from dateFrom and dateTo at time of inset

```
INSERT INTO liveRequests (customerID, destination, departure, dateFrom, dateTo, exactDate, rooms, adults, children, budgetMax, activeRequest, duration)

VALUES (@customerID,@destination,@departure,@dateFrom,@dateTo,@exactDate,@rooms,@adults,@children,@budgetMax,@activeRequest, DATEDIFF('day',@dateFrom,@dateTo))
```

Comment: Try DATEDIFF(day, @datefrom,@dateto) instead

Comment: Is it Sql Server or MySql? Can't be both....

Comment: Make this column to be calculated from dateFrom and dateTo columns

Comment: Also, if you already have the dates in the table, it doesn't make too much sense to keep the dateDiff also.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Please add back the tag for the database you are actually using.  I can say that the `datediff()` function call works in neither MySQL nor SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys found the answer myself

```
INSERT INTO liveRequests (customerID, destination, departure, dateFrom, dateTo,
        exactDate, rooms, adults, children, budgetMax, activeRequest, duration)
    VALUES (@customerID, @destination, @departure, @dateFrom, @dateTo, @exactDate,
        @rooms, @adults, @children, @budgetMax, '1', DATEDIFF(day,@dateFrom, @dateTo))
```